# Data source for financial data mining

Tags: data-mining, databases, finance

I plan to do data modeling in the financial area for my master's dissertation. I am thinking of finding the connection between a certain company or country characteristics ( x values) and their creditworthiness (here I am still looking for a y variable such as credit score, bankruptcy occurrence, etc.). Do you know in which databases I could find required input_ Company data would be great, however, most likely country data might be more accessible then I could also do the thesis based on this. Thank you and very happy about any experience you can share.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this question. You could also ask your supervisor for advice, it's part of their job.

Comment: Asking your supervisor is surely a good idea. You could also do a search for research documents on that. That way you could make sure, you have a good starting point and masybe also some refereces you can add citations from. All the best for your work and have fun!